# How to change a value if it is in 2 lists in python with matching index

Tags: python, list

If I have

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 6]
list2 = [4, 3, 5, 6]
```

how can I change the values of anything that matches between the two list? Only if the Index also matches

the desired output is

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 'match']
```

I was using this

```
for idx,x in enumerate(list1):
    if x in list2:  
        list1[idx] = 'match'
```

But this replaces the 3 and the 6

Comment: Try `["match" if i in list2 else i for i in list1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are re-assigning to the `x` variable, not changing it's content. If you want a for-loop you can try this:

```py
for idx,x in enumerate(list1):
    if x in list2:  # Assuming you meant list2 here instead of list1
        list1[idx] = 'match'
```

alternatively, a more "pythonic" way (from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793917/how-to-change-a-value-if-it-is-in-2-lists-in-python/62793981#comment111044458_62793917)) is:

```py
list1 = ["match" if i in list2 else i for i in list1]
```

Comment: Well, being the first to answer with a typo in a non-working code is really not useful... Please take your time to read the question and test your code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the typo in the original code

Comment: There still is a typo, and your code still doesn't work.

Comment: And then reposting the comment of someone else as your answer, doesn't add much.

Comment: Adding comments in an answer, especially when it is a complimentary alternative, is not against the rules or frowned upon. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126/is-it-correct-to-answer-copying-from-comments-by-other-users